# What is the shortest type of text encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes

I have the following text that I want to encrypt with a password:

"This is my secret password: 1234567890"

encrypted with AES:

SgAHzFc3vluxLqZuzZKg8dzhy918N41SUU1BfBXN8CoEDfVJ0R9hox8PT2jKYA==

pass: 12345

When I encrypt this with a password using AES, the encrypted string is 64 characters.

Is there another type of encryption that is less than 64 characters? Or maybe there is an encryption that also compresses the encrypted string?

Comment: Which program did you used?

Comment: I'm still looking. Open to suggestions.

Comment: General ciphertext expansion rate for CTR mode encoded text is 4/3 + 16 bytes + 16 to 43 bytes for authentication, so a plaintext of 38 bytes would be around 83 bytes ciphertext, yours is 64, which would mean no authentication (and actually looks too short, was it compressed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1.** is there another type of encryption that is less than 64 characters?

There is a Format Preserving Encryption(FPE) that might interest you. **FPE** is exactly designed for short plaintext spaces.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption);

> In cryptography, format-preserving encryption (FPE), refers to encrypting in such a way that the output (the ciphertext) is in the same format as the input (the plaintext). The meaning of "format" varies.
>
> - To encrypt a 16-digit credit card number so that the ciphertext is another 16-digit number.
> - To encrypt an English word so that the ciphertext is another English word.
> - To encrypt an n-bit number so that the ciphertext is another n-bit number

The NIST has two standards named [FFX](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/dff/dff-ff2-fpe-scheme-update.pdf) and [BFS](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/dff/dff-ff2-fpe-scheme-update.pdf).

However, keep in mind that, since the plaintext size is so small, someone who accesses the encryption oracle can perform a dictionary attack.

> **2.** Or maybe there is an encryption that also compresses the encrypted string?

I don't know any scheme. But you can compress plaintext before encryption. This is what we do to reduce the cost of the transfer. And note that this not about security.

Comment: Would you know of any javascript libraries that implements these 2 methods?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/topics/format-preserving-encryption) might help you. Contains implementation for various languages.

Comment: I'm actually using a Vigenère cipher that I wrote in javascript. Its this the same as a FPE encryption?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ No way. From wiki;  John Black and Phillip Rogaway which described three ways to do this. They proved that each of these techniques is as secure as the block cipher that is used to construct it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) you are using with AES. The mode of operation can have a big impact on the ciphertext expansion. There are streaming modes, such as [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)), for which the ciphertext will be the same size as the plaintext. For these modes (an pretty much any mode you would want to use in practice) you will also have to transmit a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) or IV in addition to the ciphertext.

One thing you should be aware of is that modes like CTR are [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)), which is a huge security issues. So, I highly recommend you use [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) so that you don't have these security issues. This could be done by computing an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) over the ciphertext or using an [authenticated mode](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/05/19/how-to-choose-authenticated-encryption/).